# onclick function insert query to DB with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, onclick

I'm trying to insert data into the DB by clicking a button.

This is my code:

.js file

```
        function addVote(steward_id, league_id, user_id, vote) {
    $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         async: false,
         url: "submit.php",
         data: "form=addVote&steward_id=" + steward_id + "&league_id=" + league_id + "&user_id=" + user_id + "&vote=" + vote
       }).success(function( msg ) {
              $('.success').css("display", "");
              $(".success").fadeIn(1000, "linear");
              $('.success_text').fadeIn("slow");
              $('.success_text').html(msg);
              setTimeout(function(){location.reload()},1200);
      });
}
```

.php button part

```
<button type="button" class="btn-danger" onclick="addVote(2,2,2,2)">DSQ (<?php echo $dqs; ?> votes)</button>
```

submit.php

```
            case 'addVote':
            $steward_id     = $_POST['steward_id'];
            $league_id      = $_POST['league_id'];
            $user_id        = $_POST['user_id'];
            $vote           = $_POST['vote'];
             $ez->addVote($steward_id, $league_id, $user_id, $vote);
            break;
```

the php function:

```
        function addVote($steward_id, $league_id, $user_id, $vote){

           $this->link->query("INSERT INTO `lg_vote` (`steward_id`, `user_id`, `league_id`, `vote`) VALUES ('$steward_id','$league_id', '$user_id', '$vote')");
        return;
    }
```

Anyone? Thanks!

Comment: What seems to be the problem? Are you getting an error?

Comment: Nope, nothing. Submit works, it just doesn't seem to insert into the DB.

I put the function inside the PHP page and it ran fine, also inserted into the DB. it Doesn't seem to work with the onclick

Comment: You need some error handling in your PHP - you can show the error on the page if you do not reload the page, which also does not make ANY sense. Why reload after AJAX - instead forward to submit.php and have php redirect back to the page OR update the current page with the new data from the DB

Comment: `data: {'column':data...}`  use Data field in Ajax like this...the problem might be is you are sending data in `GET` form and REQUEST METHOD is POST....

Answer (score -2):

Connect to mysql database first and then insert to table.

```
function addVote($steward_id, $league_id, $user_id, $vote){
// connect to mysql database first ;)
       $this->link->query("INSERT INTO `lg_vote` (`steward_id`, `user_id`, `league_id`, `vote`) VALUES ('$steward_id','$league_id', '$user_id', '$vote')");
    return;
}
```

Comment: I didn't include everything here since its a big file, database connection is up and works, so it's not that :(

Comment: try add VALUES without quotes ' if you using int in mysql tables! $this->link->query("INSERT INTO `lg_vote` (`steward_id`, `user_id`, `league_id`, `vote`) VALUES ($steward_id,$league_id, $user_id, $vote)");

Comment: add alert after: success(function( msg ) { alert(msg); } and see server response.

Comment: in php file add on top: error_reporting('E_ALL'); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Comment: And you can now see what is wrong with on which side.

Comment: There are no errors, when I click the button the browsers gives me a popup with some HTML/CSS lines.

Can't seem to get the alert functioning

Comment: if alert does not work! You have an error in js script

Comment: add echo "OK_WORKS"; in php script on the bottom

Comment: and see whats happen

Comment: alert should display OK_WORKS

Comment: or add to addVote function in php: echo "My_ID ".$steward_id;

Comment: then alert should display: My_ID NUMBER

Comment: You could accept answer clicking button on left side this answer.